# Determining/enabling parallelism in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have developed a scala application and I am getting almost proper results out of it. But I am not sure if my code is taking advantage of spark parallelism.

I am running spark in a standalone mode having two virtual workers with 2 cores and 2G memory each.

[image: Spark standalone setup]

Below is the code snippet from the application:

The initialization of the RDD:

```
for(i <- 0 to limit-1){
    data+=new MyClass(dimension_limit) with Serializable
}
var example_rdd = sc.parallelise(data)
```

RDD Operations:

```
var temp_rdd: RDD[MyClass] = sc.emptyRDD[MyClass]
temp_rdd = example_rdd

var updated_rdd: RDD[MyClass] = sc.emptyRDD[MyClass]

for(i <- 0 to no_of_iterations-1){
 updated_rdd = temp_rdd.map{ x => updation_function(x)} 
 updated_rdd.count() // to trigger the map
 temp_rdd = updated_rdd
}
```

Update function :

```
def update_function(x: MyClass): MyClass{
  x.property1 = "value"
  .
  .
  .
 //all updations
  return x
}
```

Below is the snapshot of the job from history server

[image: Spark Job]

and this is stage detail:

[image: stage detail]

Kindly help me to determine if my code is running parallelly; if not what might be the issue in my implementation?